# how to make result in one path?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

1. this my code :

   ```
   import java.util.Arrays;

    public class BookClasss {
    private String name;
    public AuthorClass[]  author ; 
    private double price ; 
    private int qty =0;

   public BookClasss(String names, AuthorClass[] authors, double price2,
       int qtyes)
   {

     this.name = names;

     this.author = authors;

     this.price = price2;

    this.qty = qtyes;
   }


   public void SetBookDetails (String names, AuthorClass[] authors,double price2 , int qtyes)
   {
       this.name = names;
       this.author = authors;
       this.price = price2;
       this.qty = qtyes;
   }


    public String Getbookname()
   {
      return name;
   }


   public double getprice()
   {
       return price;
   }

   public void setprice (double prices)
   {
      price = prices;
   }

   public void setQty (int qtnties)
   {
      qty = qtnties;
   }

   public int getQty ()
   {
       return qty;
   }

    public void GetAll ()
    {
       for (int i=0; i<author.length;i++)
        {
             System.out.println("Book name : "+name+", Authors :   "+Arrays.asList(author[i].ToAll())+" , Price : "+price+"");
        }

     }

   }
   ```
2. And that's the main method :

   ```
   public class TestBook 
   {
       public static void main(String[] args) 
      {

         AuthorClass[] authors = new AuthorClass[2];
         authors[0] = new AuthorClass( "John" , "John@yahoo.com" , 'M');
         authors[1] = new AuthorClass( "Sam" , "Sam@yahoo.com" , 'M');
         BookClasss book = new BookClasss("Java OOP",authors, 200.5, 20);
         book.GetAll();

      }

   }
   ```
3. And the output is :

   ```
     Book name : Java OOP, Authors : [Author Name=John , Mail = John@yahoo.com] , Price : 120.2
     Book name : Java OOP, Authors : [Author Name=Sam , Mail = Sam@yahoo.com] , Price : 120.2
   ```

   i used forloop to get all of authors array result but i want to print the result be like  :

   ```
   Book name : Java OOP, Authors : [Author Name=John , Mail = John@yahoo.com] ,  [Author Name=Sam , Mail = Sam@yahoo.com] ,  Price : 120.2
   ```

   in one result without repeating book name and price .. how can i do it ?
   Can anyone Help me ???

Comment: Classes shouldn't have `Class` in the name.

Comment: Just like you don't name a method `getAllMethod()` or a variable `nameVariable`, a class shouldn't be called `AuthorClass`.

Comment: Also, the standard Java convention is to start method names with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void GetAll ()
 {
    System.out.println("Book name : "+name+", Authors :   ");
    for (int i=0; i<author.length;i++)
     {
          System.out.print(Arrays.asList(author[i].ToAll())+" ,"); 
     }
     System.out.println("Price : "+price+"");
  }
```

Comment: but what u mean by  Classes shouldn't have Class in the name.  ?? @shmosel

Comment: Post that in the question comments.

Comment: Wrong section, again.

Comment: He just may not notice it.